# Shouldn't shutil.copyfile replace link in dst with follow_symlinks set?

Tags: python, python-3.x, symlink, shutil

Maybe I'm just missing something but this confused me a bit and hence the question in title.

Python's `shutil.copyfile()` has a `follow_symlinks` argument but it only affects the source, not the destination - i.e. when `src` is a symlink, it makes a difference whether the flag is set (and then it will copy the destination of that `src` symlink) or not (and then it will just create a new symlink in `dst` pointing to the `src` symlink's destination). I hope it's clear so far.

When `dst` is a link though, the flag doesn't change anything and it will always copy that file to the `dst` symlink's destination.

My question is... If `dst` is a symlink and `follow_symlinks` flag is not set,  wouldn't it be more logical if the `dst` symlink was just replaced by a copy of `src` instead of copying `src` to `dst`'s destination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I [suggested](https://bugs.python.org/issue34374) this in Python issue tracker and apparently it is intentional and the reason is that POSIX cp command behaves the same way.